The counting argument
Here on the page 264
I do not understand the counting argument:
Even in one function
and one set this part is unclear to me: $2^{2^{2^{2^{n(m+1)}}}}$ from which (this is what I do understand) it follows this is $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}} = 265,536$.
EDIT:
For PBRT in σ on (V,K), where σ is based on m functions and n sets, we cannot specify the assertions by a single format. Instead, what is relevant is the number of all α formulas up to propositional and Boolean equivalence. The number of α equations, up to Boolean equivalence, is 2^2^n(m+1), and so the number of α formulas up to
propositional and Boolean equivalence is 2^2^2^2^n(m+1). This quantity is quite frightening. Even in one function and one set, this is 2^2^2^2^2 = 265,536. For one function and two sets, this is 2^2^2^2^4 = 2^2^65,636. These numbers do not address two functions and three sets. We do not tackle PBRT in this book.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I just do not understand how it has been obtained that number:this is $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}} = 265,536$. I understand that some machinery with propositional formulas has been employed but do not know how exactly.

You've written the number incorrectly, the book says the result is $2^{65,536}$, which follows directly from the fact that $2^{2^{2^2}} = 2^{2^4} = 2^{16}= 65,536$.

If the comment of infinitylord has resolved your question, fine.  If not, please edit your posted question accordingly, clarifying your remaining question.  In that event, it is asking a lot of a MathSE reviewer to carefully browse the lengthy pdf in order to attack any remaining question that you have.  I suggest that you therefore, delete the pdf link, and provide all of the needed definitions/specifications directly in your posted question, still keeping your posted question as clear as possible, and (within that) as well organized and as short as possible.

@user2661923 I just want to understand why the number of α formulas up to propositional and Boolean equivalence is $2^{2^{2^{2^{n(m+1)}}}}$. It is just manipulation with propositional formulae so nothing has to be written down.
